# SQL trigger for checking if a user is alread in a table

Tags: sql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger that executes when a new user is added to a table.  When the user is added, I need the trigger to check the table to see if the user already exists, and if it does, to spit out an error message saying the user already exists.  Otherwise, the insert should go through.

```
ALTER TRIGGER tR_CustomerCheck ON CUSTOMER 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
IF EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM CUSTOMER AS C
        JOIN inserted as I
            ON C.UserID  = I.UserID 
    WHERE C.UserID = I.UserID )
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Customer already exists.';
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END;
```

It appears that the row gets inserted, then checked so it always fails.  I am sure it has to be a simple fix, but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: Why a trigger? A foreign key constraint to the customer table will suffice.

Comment: I agree that a foreign key would work better/be easier to maintain, but in this instance, it must be a trigger.

Comment: I suppose you cannot check existence on the front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `FOR/AFTER` trigger, use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.  Though I have to agree with wildplasser's comment.  This is a textbook utilization of a unique constraint.

Comment: I had tried to use INSTEAD OF but when I switch it in the trigger, nothing happens when I try to insert a valid row.  It catches the code if it already exists, but doesn't insert the row if it is new.

Comment: @THansenite Can you post your `INSTEAD OF` trigger code in your question?  Also, why don't you go with a constraint?